# VBA code to save PDF does not work properly

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I have set up a command button to save the current worksheet as a PDF file. I have played around with this code for several hours and almost got it to work properly but it seems I have disconnected some areas and cannot find my way back. Please see below for the code that I am using and the variables I am having an issue with at this point. Any help or information would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Issues:

1. When you click 'Cancel' in the save application box, the document still tries to save.
2. If the file already exists:

   - Selecting 'Yes' to over-write does not save the document.
   - Selecting 'No' to over-write and renaming as another already existing document does not prompt another Question box to over-write or not. It simply over-writes the original document name.

     ```
     Sub PDFFHA()
     Dim wsA As Worksheet
     Dim wbA As Workbook
     Dim strName As String
     Dim strPath As String
     Dim strFile As String
     Dim strPathFile As String
     Dim myFile As Variant
     On Error GoTo errHandler

     Set wbA = ActiveWorkbook
     Set wsA = ActiveSheet

     strPath = "I:\OCC FRB REMIC Reporting\Quality Control\PDFs"
     If strPath = "" Then
       strPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
     End If
     strPath = strPath & "\"

     strName = Replace(wsA.Range("D3"), " ", "")
     strName = Replace(strName, ".", "_")

     strFile = "FHA" & "_" & strName & "_" & "QC" & ".pdf"
     strPathFile = strPath & strFile

     myFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
         (InitialFileName:=strPathFile, _
             FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
             Title:="Select Folder and FileName to save")

     If bFileExists(strPathFile) Then
         lOver = MsgBox("Overwrite existing file?", _
           vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "File Exists")
         If lOver <> vbYes Then
           myFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
               (InitialFileName:=strPathFile, _
                   FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
                   Title:="Select Folder and FileName to save")
           If myFile <> "False" Then
             wsA.ExportAsFixedFormat _
                 Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                 Filename:=strPathFile, _
                 Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                 IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                 IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                 OpenAfterPublish:=False
             MsgBox "PDF file has been created: " _
                 & vbCrLf _
                 & strPathFile

           Else
             GoTo exitHandler
           End If
         End If
     Else
         wsA.ExportAsFixedFormat _
             Type:=xlTypePDF, _
             Filename:=strPathFile, _
             Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
             IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
             IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
             OpenAfterPublish:=False
         MsgBox "PDF file has been created: " _
           & vbCrLf _
           & strPathFile
     End If

     exitHandler:
         Exit Sub
     errHandler:
         MsgBox "Could not create PDF file"
         Resume exitHandler
     End Sub
     '=============================
     Function bFileExists(rsFullPath As String) As Boolean
       bFileExists = CBool(Len(Dir$(rsFullPath)) > 0)
     End Function
     '=============================
     ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some clean-up and re-formatting.

If the file already exists, you are prompted to overwrite or not. The code only checks for the response to be `vbNo` since `vbYes` implies that `strPathFile` remains the same, i.e. no action needed. The loop handles a Cancel click, as well as the possibility that your new `strPathFile` is again an existing file.

```
Option Explicit

Sub PDF_FHA()

Dim wsA As Worksheet: Set wsA = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Dim strName, strPath, strFile, strPathFile As String

On Error GoTo errHandler

' Get path
strPath = "I:\OCC FRB REMIC Reporting\Quality Control\PDFs\"

' Get and clean filename
strName = Replace(wsA.Range("D3"), " ", "")
strName = Replace(strName, ".", "_")
strFile = "FHA_" & strName & "_QC.pdf"
strPathFile = strPath & strFile

' Check if file exists, prompt overwrite
If bFileExists(strPathFile) Then
    If MsgBox("Overwrite existing file?", _
      vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "File Exists") = vbNo Then

        Do
        strPathFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
          (InitialFileName:=strPathFile, _
              FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
              Title:="Select Folder and FileName to save")

        ' Handle cancel
        If strPathFile = "False" Then Exit Sub

        ' Loop if new filename still exists
        Loop While bFileExists(strPathFile)

    End If
End If

wsA.ExportAsFixedFormat _
            Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:=strPathFile, _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=False

MsgBox "PDF file has been created: " _
            & vbCrLf _
            & strPathFile

Exit Sub

errHandler:
    MsgBox "Could not create PDF file"

End Sub

'=============================
Function bFileExists(rsFullPath As String) As Boolean
  bFileExists = CBool(Len(Dir$(rsFullPath)) > 0)
End Function
'=============================
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, turn `Option Explicit` on.

Follow the logic in `If lOver <> vbYes Then`. With the proper indenting you will see that it only handles the `<> vbYes` path and does not have an `Else`.

1. So, you do not actually handle the "Yes" case.
2. Your "No" logic only brings up a file dialog box and we don't know what you have done to test this (cancel, put new name in, just accept name as presented?). However, there is no additional question on this logic path.  If you don't hit "Cancel" to the file dialog it will just save the file.